# Asymptotics of $\sum_{x = 0}^{\alpha n} {n \choose x}$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, asymptotics

> Let $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. What is the asymptotic growth of the following function? $$\sum_{x = 0}^{\alpha n} {n \choose x}$$

I am aware that ${n \choose \alpha n}$ grows asymptotically as a constant times $\left( \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha} \right)^{\alpha n} \left( \frac{1}{1 - \alpha} \right)^n$, but I can't seem to find the asymptotic growth of the previous function I had mentioned. I tried taking an integral from $x = 0$ to $\alpha n$ of the quantity
$$\left( \frac{n-x}{x} \right)^x \left( \frac{n}{n-x} \right)^n$$
but I can't find the closed form expression of this integral. Does anybody have a better idea?

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent (tight asymptotics), a $\Theta(\cdot)$ sort of asymptotics, or only a $O(\cdot)$?

Comment: A tight asymptotic would be preferable, but a close upper bound would suffice.

Comment: May  be relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n and http://mathoverflow.net/a/55617/37266

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: As $n \to \infty$, ${n \choose x} \sim {n^{x} \over x!}$.